# mysql server has gone away error during installing migration (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, migrate

So I am using my cmd on my laravel folder and I tried to do (php artisan migrate:install). 2 errors came up.

1. > [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
2. > [ErrorException] PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away

Can anyone please explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a Laravel issue, but a general MySQL Issue. Maybe the server is not running. Are you sure you're running MySQL in the background?

Check this link: [MySQL Gone Away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html)

Do the following checks in your system:

1. The Database Engine is running
2. You have created your database
3. You have created an user and granted permissions to the database
4. You have setup the user and the database in your Laravel's .env file.

After this, try to run the migrations command again, which is:

```
php artisan migrate
```

As explained [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#running-migrations)

Let us know if that helps :).

Answer (score 9):

You have Lost SQL connection to server during query. It is temporally issue. This is because of very low default setting of `max_allowed_packet`.

Raising `max_allowed_packet` in `my.cnf` (under [mysqld]) to 8 or 16M usually fixes it.

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

**NOTE:** This can be set on your server as it's running. You need to `restart` the MySQL service once you are done.

Use: `set global max_allowed_packet=104857600`. My value sets it to 100MB.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem seemed to be that I assigned the wrong port to my Laravel project's `.env` file. Later, when I matched it with the `my.cnf` file, it worked.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 + nginx + MariaDB + Laravel project.

Comment: Same Issue. I assigned a wrong port for my DB connections in ENV.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. The solution was  to delete the mysql port number from 3306 or 80, and leave it empty
In files

**.env** `DB_PORT=3306` to `DB_PORT=`
and on

**database.php**  `'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),`    to     `'port' => env('DB_PORT', ''),`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was I changed `DB_HOST` to `localhost` but it was fixed by keeping it `default` ie `127.0.0.1` and the port to default `3306`.
Here is the configuration for localhost in xampp:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=hmb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Although I use `localhost:8081/phpmyadmin` to access my `db`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers:

- Try changing `localhost` domain to `127.0.0.1` both in `.env` and `config/database.php`.
- Also If you're using `git` then check `git status` and see if any unwanted files have been changed.

Because In my case `options` array for mysql connection configuration in file `config/database.php` was blank array somehow. I checked out `git checkout config/database.php` file and it starting to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a solution, try to clean all cache you have, you can manually delete cache files in **bootstrap/cache** folder.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is due to fix the DB_HOST parameter. Indeed I use PHPStorm and I set the public url in .env in order to use DB tools from the IDE and this broken Laravel.
So I changed DB_HOST to localhost and Laravel now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on my XAMPP dev server while running a lot of Laravel unit tests. Configuration for XAMPP MySQL is located at `C:\XAMPP\mysql\bin\my.ini`. Open that file, look for the `max_allowed_packet` option (under the `[mysqld]` header). By default this is set to 1 megabyte (probably 1 mebibyte to be more accurate).

Simply change it to something large enough to prevent you from running into this issue again:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=32M
```

Then restart the MySQL service from the XAMPP Control Panel to force the changes to take effect.