# How to fix this "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away" when i try to input my data?

Tags: mysql, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGO93.png)

### this shows the error when i tried migrating it.

So I am trying to input my data from a register form I make myself.

I've tried changing the `my.cnf` file to set the `max_allowed_packet` to 16MB or 32MB but that still didn't work.

This is my RegisterController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/login';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'address' =>$data['address'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

This is my register.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And this is my web.php

```
<?php


Route::resource('home', 'CustomerController');

Route::get('/login', function () {
return view('login');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/', function (){
return view('home');
});

Route::get('/form', [
'uses' => 'ContactMessageController@create'
]);

Route::post('/form', [
'uses' => 'ContactMessageController@store',
'as' => 'form.store'
]);

Route::post('sendemail', ['as' => 'sendemail', 'uses' => 'ContactMessageController@store']);
```

So when I click on the submit button, it'll show the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Please help

this is my .env file

```
    APP_NAME=Laravel
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:Fdkk8GmjtoJ98UdC44AE7cQ0MWvWKZen0WIssiR1/LA=
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    APP_URL=http://localhost

    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=85
    DB_DATABASE=Internship
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=

    BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
    CACHE_DRIVER=file
    SESSION_DRIVER=file
    SESSION_LIFETIME=120
    QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

    REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
    REDIS_PASSWORD=null
    REDIS_PORT=6379

    MAIL_DRIVER=log
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME=null
    MAIL_PASSWORD=null
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

    PUSHER_APP_ID=
    PUSHER_APP_KEY=
    PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
    PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Comment: Can you please post your .env file?  Also, what platform are you running on?  My gut is telling me that this problem has nothing to do with your Laravel setup.

Comment: i've posted is @MichaelMiller

Comment: Can you post the last 50 lines of you MySQL error log file (normally located at /var/log/mysql/ (this is a guess, as I don't know what Linux distro you're running), and assuming you have the proper tools to run `sudo service mysql status` (again, a guess because I don't know what Linux distro you're running), but I'm curious to see the output of that command as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Laravel issue, but a general MySQL Issue. Maybe the server is not running. Are you sure you're running MySQL in the background?

Check this link: [MySQL Gone Away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html)

Do the following checks in your system:

1. The Database Engine is running
2. You have created your database
3. You have created an user and granted permissions to the database
4. You have setup the user and the database in your Laravel's .env file.

After this, try to run the migrations command again, which is:

```
php artisan migrate
```

As explained [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#running-migrations)

Credits to @Andrés Smerkin 
[mysql server has gone away error during installing migration (laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036547/mysql-server-has-gone-away-error-during-installing-migration-laravel)

Comment: i've tried it, but it shows the error in the terminal. see my original post for the screenshot

Comment: why is your mysql port 85? Default is 3306

Answer (score 0):

In general this error can also be a result of misconfigured SSL/TLS if SSL/TLS is set up towards the MySQL DB.

Answer (score -1):

Hello i had the same issue but i will ask you to check if the user of your database had all priveleges to create, update and delete.
so for exmple in my case i went to phpmyadmin i was searching fro the user which i use in my .env file for example
login :root
passwod : root
i also think you're missing somthing with the port
mysql default port are 3306
so the user in my case is root
i went to phpmyadmin to the home  then in the user acount server privileges
make sure the user had the same config
root    localhost    YES ALL PRIVILEGES YES